# XSLT: Return results based on following sibling value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'am fairly new to XSLT. Any help would be appreciated ....

```
<Test>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="1" Segment_id="3" >
     <usage_id>1</usage_id>
    <value>41</value>
  </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="2"  Segment_id="3">
    <usage_id>1</usage_id>
     <value>2</value>
      </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="4" Segment_id="3">
     <usage_id>2</usage_id>
     <value>raj</value>
      </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="5" Segment_id="3">
     <usage_id>3</usage_id>
      <value>d</value>
    </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="6" Segment_id="3">
    <usage_id>3</usage_id>  
      <value>8</value>
  </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="7" Segment_id="3">
    <usage_id>3</usage_id>
      <value>7</value>
  </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="1" Segment_id="4">
       <usage_id>1</usage_id>

    <value>IC</value>
      </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="2" Segment_id="4">
  <usage_id>2</usage_id>
      <value>d</value> 
  </loop>
 <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="3" Segment_id="4">
      <usage_id>3</usage_id>
          <value>dm</value> 
      </loop> 
 <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="4" Segment_id="4">
      <usage_id>2</usage_id>
          <value>wj</value> 
      </loop> 
    </Test>
```

I would like to return the 'value' only if its usage_id is either 1 or 2. In case if the usage_id is 3 it should return "N/A".
However, for example if am in Segment_id=3 LoopElementOrder_no=5 then the remaining of Segment_id=3 doesn't contains any Usage_id as 1 or 2 in which case i need to return "^" and continue the it from Segment_id=4 with LoopElementOrder_no=1.

The desired output for the above is:

```
41 2 raj ^IC d N/A wj
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your expected output in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tim. Here is output same for above case 41 2 raj ^IC d

Comment: So could you show us an example of an input that would result in having "N/A" in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A shorter, simpler (only three templates, no `xsl:apply-templates`, no `xsl:variable`, no `current()` and no modes) and more understandable solution that is completely in "push style":**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="loop[not(usage_id >2)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(value, ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "loop[usage_id = 3
     and preceding-sibling::loop[not(usage_id >2)][1]/@Segment_id
        =following-sibling::loop[not(usage_id >2)][1]/@Segment_id
      ]
 ">N/A </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "loop
   [usage_id >2
  and
    preceding-sibling::loop[1][not(usage_id >2)]
  and
    not(@Segment_id =following-sibling::loop[not(usage_id >2)][1]/@Segment_id)
    ]">^ </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Test>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="1" Segment_id="3" >
     <usage_id>1</usage_id>
    <value>41</value>
  </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="2"  Segment_id="3">
    <usage_id>1</usage_id>
     <value>2</value>
      </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="4" Segment_id="3">
     <usage_id>2</usage_id>
     <value>raj</value>
      </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="5" Segment_id="3">
     <usage_id>3</usage_id>
      <value>d</value>
    </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="6" Segment_id="3">
    <usage_id>3</usage_id>
      <value>8</value>
  </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="7" Segment_id="3">
    <usage_id>3</usage_id>
      <value>7</value>
  </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5" LoopElementOrder_no="1" Segment_id="4">
       <usage_id>1</usage_id>

    <value>IC</value>
      </loop>
  <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="2" Segment_id="4">
  <usage_id>2</usage_id>
      <value>d</value>
  </loop>
 <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="3" Segment_id="4">
      <usage_id>3</usage_id>
          <value>dm</value>
      </loop>
 <loop loop_id="5"  LoopElementOrder_no="4" Segment_id="4">
      <usage_id>2</usage_id>
          <value>wj</value>
      </loop>
</Test>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
41 2 raj ^ IC d N/A wj
```

---

**Update**:

**The solution can be shortened and simplified even more:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="loop[not(usage_id >2)]">
   <xsl:if test=
   "preceding-sibling::loop[not(usage_id >2)][1]
      [not(@Segment_id = current()/@Segment_id)]">^ </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(value, ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "loop[usage_id = 3
     and preceding-sibling::loop[not(usage_id >2)][1]/@Segment_id
        =following-sibling::loop[not(usage_id >2)][1]/@Segment_id
      ]
 ">N/A </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="loop">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(value, ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="loop[usage_id = 3]">
    <xsl:variable name="segmentId" select="@Segment_id" />
    <xsl:variable name="following12"
                  select="following-sibling::loop[@Segment_id = $segmentId]
                                                 [usage_id = 1 or usage_id = 2]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="current()[not(preceding-sibling::loop[1]
                                                   [@Segment_id = $segmentId]
                                                   [usage_id = 3])
                        and not($following12)]" mode="carat" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[$following12]" mode="na" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="loop" mode="na">
    <xsl:text>N/A </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="loop" mode="carat">
    <xsl:text>^</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
41 2 raj ^IC d N/A wj
```